# Cant do SQL select statement with socket.io

Tags: javascript, sql, socket.io

When trying to get the password for the exact userid that the user types in, it gives me this error code: Database {}
error looking up if user exists Error: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range

im able to get the value for "hashedpassword", but i cant get the value for getpassword. Im not sure if it is my sql statement that fails. if i put a valid testname instead of socket.username it gives me the same error, so it must be something with the database extraction.

app.js

```
    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = validator.escape(username);
    socket.password = validator.escape(password);
       
    const salt = 'Some salt for the hash';
  
   const hashedPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(socket.password, salt, 1000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');

   
    db.serialize(function() {
      
      var checkIfUserExists = "select count(*) from users where username = '" + socket.username +"'";
      var getPassword = `SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = "${socket.username}"`
     console.log(db.get(getPassword))
      db.get(checkIfUserExists, getPassword, function(err, row) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('error looking up if user exists', err);
          return;
        }
        if (row['count(*)'] === 0) {
          // console.log("user doesn't exist!");
          socket.emit('alertuserdoesntexists');
        } 
      
        if (getPassword === hashedPassword) {
          console.log("virker")
          
        
          socket.emit('redirect');
}})
```

chat.js

```
      var $usernameInput = $('.usernameInput'); // Input for username

      username = $usernameInput.val();
      password = $passwordInput.val();

      // Tell the server your username
      socket.emit('existing user', username, password)
    });
```